# Show F-keys disabled or enabled on Status Bar?

Tags: byobu

How do I show status of "shift-F12" on status bar? This is useful when I have nested byobu sessions.

I set this line in `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf` and it only reflexes status of `F12`:

`set -g status-right "#{?client_prefix,#[fg=color33]Prefix Activated...,[#S]}"`

### Update:

I would like to set: If `shift-F12` is enabled, the status says: `F-keys` in bold green. Otherwise says: `F-keys` in bold red. I could copy contents of `/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux*` to `$HOME/.byobu`, modified them and sourced from there. It works but I hope there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Can you include the file contents under both conditions: on and off? I'll write an answer tonight if a better one isn't posted by then.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Please check the update in the question. Thanks

Comment: I still don't understand what file contains the current status for F12 and how you tell if it is off or on. Can you update your question with the command you run and the output it produces in the two different circumstances: OFF and ON

Answer (score 0):

I use in byobu `tmux list-keys | grep " S-F12"` to show the status of the shift-F12 keybinding.

When on it is:

`bind-key  -T root  S-F12  source-file /usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux.disable \; display-message "Byobu F-keys: DISABLED"`

In case it is off it shows:

`bind-key  -T root  S-F12  source-file /usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux \; source-file /home/sp/.byobu/keybindings.tmux \; display-message "Byobu F-keys: ENABLED"`

Hitting F9 you can enable custom scripts. These scripts go into ~/.byobu/bin.  For details see [Byobu Custom Status Notifications in 3 Easy Steps](https://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2010/01/byobu-custom-status-notifications-in-3.html).

My script updates every 2 seconds and creates a keybinding status, the script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
tmp=$(tmux list-keys | grep " S-F12")

echo $tmp | grep "DISABLED" > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        # keybindings currently active, will be deactivated with next shift-F12
        echo "#[fg=white,bold,bg=green]KB:on#[default]"
else
        # keybindings currently inactive, will be activated with next shift-F12
        echo "#[fg=white,bold,bg=red]KB:off#[default]"
fi
```

I named the script `02_keybindings` - the 02 indicates the update every 2 seconds.

#######

In case one doesn't want to run such a script like every two seconds there is another hack. Byobu caches the status values in `/dev/shm/byobu-USER-RANDOMVALUE/cache.tmux/custom.SCRIPTNAME`. Writing the same value like `"#[fg=white,bold,bg=green]KB:on#[default]"` to that file updates the status line almost immediately. One could set then the script to update just every 60 seconds. It is still needed - otherwise the custom status is gone.

The directory one gets through

```
[ -r "$HOME/.byoburc" ] && . "$HOME/.byoburc"
[ -z "${BYOBU_PREFIX}" ] && export BYOBU_PREFIX="/usr" || export BYOBU_PREFIX
. "${BYOBU_PREFIX}/lib/${PKG}/include/common"

cachepath="$BYOBU_RUN_DIR/cache.tmux/custom."${0##*/}""
```

And to run that script which updates the cache file one could update the key binding for shift-F12 to not only source f-keys.tmux... but also run that script.